# How to insert multiple, increasing by 1, rows to mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, resteasy

I want to add 30 rows to my SQL database. The table has 3 columns: "Year", "Month", "Day". The rows should by added to "Day" column. I use the following code, as I want to do it **once**. When I post it through RESTeasy I can see in PHPmyadmin that only **last row** was added, in this case: "2017" "1" "31".

```
// Add days in month
$app->post('/api/calendar/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $year = $request->getParam('Year');
    $month = $request->getParam('Month');
    $day = $request->getParam('Day');

    $day = 1;
    while($day < 31) {
        $day = $day + 1;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `days` (`Year`, `Month`, `Day`) VALUES ('2017', '1', '$day')";
        }; 

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
        // Connect
        $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

        $stmt = $dbcalendar->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':Year', $year);
        $stmt->bindParam('Month', $month);
        $stmt->bindParam('Day', $day);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Days Added"}';

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move `try catch` into the while

```
// Add days in month
$app->post('/api/calendar/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $year = $request->getParam('Year');
    $month = $request->getParam('Month');
    $day = $request->getParam('Day');

    $day = 1;
    while($day < 31) {
        $day = $day + 1;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `days` (`Year`, `Month`, `Day`) VALUES ('2017', '1', '$day')";

        try {
            // Get DB Object
            $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
            // Connect
            $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

            $stmt = $dbcalendar->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindParam(':Year', $year);
            $stmt->bindParam('Month', $month);
            $stmt->bindParam('Day', $day);

            $stmt->execute();

            echo '{"notice": {"text": "Days Added"}';

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Very simple and efficient solution. I forgot about `$stmt = $dbcalendar->prepare($sql);` and `$stmt->execute();` which have to executed for each and every sql querry in this very case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sql` variable is being overwritten in each execution of your `while` loop. Hence, after 31 executions, it looks like :

```
INSERT INTO `days` (`Year`, `Month`, `Day`) VALUES ('2017', '1', '31')
```

I can think of at least two different approaches to fix this :

Either put your `try...catch` statement inside your `while`. This way, each time the request is built, it is executed.

Or transform your `$sql` var into an array and add every values set as a new entry, then `implode` it. This way, you'll have a single SQL request and execution :

```
$sql_array = array();
while($day < 31) {
    $day = $day + 1;
    $sql_array[] = "('2017', '1', '$day')";
};
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `days` (`Year`, `Month`, `Day`) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $sql_array);
```

While the first method might be easier to understand, the second one will definitely require less resources and have a shorter execution time.

Comment: I have just tried the `try...catch` solution, but thanks for thorough answear anyway.